# Unknown host 'ûs:Filename error in batch

Tags: batch-file

This error is giving me below error
**Unknown host ûs:Script.txt**.
It is creating the Script.txt file successfully with all inputs to it.

below is the code

```
 @echo off
   set /p host="enter your hostname to connect to "     
   Echo open %host%>Script.txt


   set /p user="enter your login id "  
   Echo %user%>>Script.txt

  set /p pass="enter your password " 
  Echo %pass%>>Script.txt

  echo cd /osp/local/var/trace/>>Script.txt

  set /p foldername="enter the foldername"
  mkdir %foldername%

  Echo lcd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%foldername%\>>Script.txt

  set /p filename="enter the pattern like *.extn or file name with spaces"
  Echo mget /Y %filename%>>Script.txt

  start ftp.exe -s:Script.txt
```

Comment: looks like encoding issue.What the notepad tells you about the file encoding?

Comment: Your issues is the start ftp line, for some reason the minus sign is being seen as û, so ftp never actually opens Script.txt. Try just deleting and retyping the - or alternatively use /s:Script.txt which is also valid

Comment: try also with `start "" /w ftp.exe -s:Script.txt` or `start "" /w ftp.exe /s:Script.txt`

Comment: @ScottC Thanks Dear it worked for me.
and it also seems that the script was working differently on different systems.
I tried running the code in two other systems(same os WIN 7) but at One system it was working properly and in another not.